# 32-bit process not started in windows docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, process

I have a simple 32 bit commandline application (CPP application), which is started using C# in ASP.NET Core.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Application");
```

It is working fine in 32-bit/64-bit application when testing on serveral windows OS (32-bit/64-bit).

When running the application in docker container, it does not launch the 32-bit application.

If I use the simple 64-bit applcation, then it is launching properly. But I could not build my CPP application to 64-bit, as its dependencies are 32-bit.

Docker container : windows/amd64

Can anyone please help me to overcome this? I'm new to docker.

Comment: Any Stacktrace from deployed application?

Comment: @Black.Jack, There is no exception from docker, my simple 64-bit CPP application shows the output text from standard output of the process. But the same cpp project built as 32-bit, it does not shows the output text from standard output of the process. It happens only in windows docker container, but both applications are working fine in my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way of running 32-bit applications in containers. You might find some obscure ways to create 32-bit containers though. But it involves a lot of work and such a container would *only* support 32-bit applications.

Cheers!